# My dog keeps twisting his body, arching his back, and rubbing his back and butt on walls and bushes

Tags: dogs, behavior

The thing is, it's only when we're on our way back from a walk. Leaving the house and walking is fine, he'll rub some bushes but he won't arch his back or bite/sniff his rear. But when we're homeward bound he begins to do this. Should I be concerned? Has anyone else seen this behavior before?

I should mention he is a 5 year old Cockapoo and is fixed.

Comment: He just had a vet appointment to get his vaccines, and I got him groomed. I think the groomers may have voided his sacs as part of the process. I'll consult my vet.

Comment: Isn't that normal though? To prevent build up? I learned about it in middle school but I haven't exactly kept up with the practice 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sudden changes in behavior can indicate a problem - have you asked your vet? If he's doing his business on these walks prior to the odd behavior - [possibly something related to his anal glands](http://pets.webmd.com/anal-sac-disease-dogs)?

Groomers are not vets. If your groomer is voiding your dogs anal sacs as a matter of course with regular visits, it may be causing the problem. If they've only done it the once, it may be their technique is inappropriate. Imagine popping a zit with too much pressure and bruising or damaging the skin. Maybe your fingernails cut into the skin as you are frustrated by the zit not popping. Imagine doing this every day. Imagine you don't like doing this because when the zit pops it really stinks. Imagine you don't get paid much to do this and mostly do it because someone told you that you have to... Next thing you know: irritation, infection, etc. Talk to your vet and in the meantime tell your groomer to leave the anal glands alone.

Comment: Thanks! I called the vet and they want to just take a look, so I'm planning on going this Saturday. I'll let them know about the grooming and his behavior, etc.

Comment: @AngelJosephPiscola glad to hear that. I hope everything is okay - please do let the community know if you find a resolution to this issue!

Comment: Vet determined there was an infection in one of his anal glands. He's on antibiotics and an NSAID anti-inflammatory, in two weeks he's going back for a followup. Thanks!

FYI The internal sacs were not even touched, the vets were only doing the external ones according to the vet.

Comment: @AngelJosephPiscola glad to hear your vet is on top of it and you found out the reason your dog was acting so - hopefully your pooch feel sbetter soon!